# Why won't this view controller init? (NEVER MIND)

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

In trying to debug why a view controller is initing empty, I've ended up a sort of weird place. Check this out:

```
OffersSearchController *searchController = [[OffersSearchController alloc]
        initWithNibName:@"This is a completely bogus nib name."
             bundle:nil];
```

Not a single complaint. I've seen that sort of construct crash out with complaints about being unable to find a nib named "This is a completely bogus...", but not this time. Instead, my searchController pushes onto the navigation controller as if it had loaded successfully. It's empty, though--I can see the full screen of another view that's (accidentally!) "underneath" my UINavigationController stack.

What's happening here? Is `[OffersSearchController alloc]` coming back nil for some reason?

EDIT: Never mind. Here's the lesson: don't implement `loadView` when you mean to implement `viewDidLoad`. Oy. Long week.

Comment: Might want to just post your solution as an answer and accept it.  Might make things a bit easier for others who might find this question on google in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer (thanks @Eric Petroelje for suggesting I post and accept the answer).

In a burst of late-Friday-afternoon productivity, moving far faster than is recommended, I set up my property initializers and picker-wheel-data-source arrays in `-(void)loadView` rather than in `-(void)viewDidLoad`.

Rather than the `initWithNibName:` call's call to loadView being allowed to propagate up to UIViewController, it happily initialized my fields and that's all.

Answer (score -2):

[The documentation for `UIViewController initWithNibName:bundle`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) doesn't say anything about what happens if the specified nib name is invalid. Presumably then, an invalid nib name is treated the same as a nil one. However, it does say that the return value is always an initialized UIViewController.

So, what that code is doing is to allocate/initialize a new OffersSearchController with no nib. The view appears empty because it is. You've probably never actually seen that crash before, because it's not supposed to; what's happening is perfectly normal.

Comment: If u specify an invalid nib name, the app will crash actually